# Meaning of _gläubig_ in this context

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

There is a famous and often quoted sentence by Albert Einstein, which reads:

> Für uns gläubige Physiker hat die Scheidung zwischen Vergangenheit, Gegenwart und Zukunft nur die Bedeutung einer wenn auch hartnäckigen Illusion.

It was written in a condolence letter to the family of his deceased friend Michele Besso, and short before Einstein's own death.

I'm in doubt about the exact meaning of *gläubig* here. In general, if I understand correctly, this adjective may refer either to someone believing in a specific religion, or to someone who is trustful in something, not necessarily of a religious character. In different translations into English or Italian, I find *uns gläubige Physiker* translated in different ways, mostly “us believing physicists” and “us, who believe in physics”.

Is there any element – as far as possible internal to the text and to German language and as little as possible resorting to other Einstein's texts and what we generally know about him – that can actually lead us to understand that this occurrence of *gläubig* is to be considered as a secular concept rather than a religious one?

EDIT: Source for the quote: Pierre Speziali (Hrsg.): Albert Einstein – Michele Besso. *Correspondance 1903–1955*, Hermann, Paris 1972 (the standard edition of Einstein-Besso letters, with the German text and the French translation); the letter quoted here is dated 21 March 1955. The quote itself appears in several other books, for instance [here](https://books.google.it/books?id=sh4mooxCQDAC&pg=PA114&lpg=PA114&dq=f%C3%BCr+uns+gl%C3%A4ubige+physiker&source=bl&ots=Krn9hN8Mpl&sig=ACfU3U0nAWBGokP2XlgrV7CyMZjd60gxlg&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjDj5mRyOfoAhUNtosKHa6_BGI4ChDoATAAegQIChAo#v=onepage&q=f%C3%BCr%20uns%20gl%C3%A4ubige%20physiker&f=false) and [here](https://books.google.it/books?id=uWEmAQAAQBAJ&pg=PA19&lpg=PA19&dq=f%C3%BCr+uns+gl%C3%A4ubige+physiker&source=bl&ots=nruz85AAUD&sig=ACfU3U1rUyrW3Ebb1xWt2Gj0nb8rJnkRfA&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjDj5mRyOfoAhUNtosKHa6_BGI4ChDoATAGegQIChBN#v=onepage&q=f%C3%BCr%20uns%20gl%C3%A4ubige%20physiker&f=false). On Christie's website there is [a reproduction of the manuscript letter](https://www.christies.com/features/Einstein-letters-to-Michele-Besso-8422-1.aspx).

Comment: From the quote itself I'd deny any hint if Einstein meant it as "believe in logics thus in physics" or as "we as physicists who believe in a god". It might be a very good ambiguity. Any research could focus on historical documents where Einstein talks about religion and/or science.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a more detailed answer please take a look at ["Die Zeit – eine Illusion?" by Hans Joachim Störig](http://www.scheidewege.de/pdf/testseiten36/397-398_Stoerig.pdf).

Störig writes

> Was meint er mit dem Ausdruck „gläubige Physiker“? Eins ist sicher: Bestimmt meint er nicht Gläubige im Sinne der jüdischen oder der christlichen Religion. Dem Christentum hat Einstein niemals nahe gestanden. Vom jüdischen Glauben seiner Vorfahren hat er sich ausdrücklich losgesagt.
>
> What did the expression "believing physicists" mean? One thing is certain: He certainly does not mean believers in the sense of the Jewish or Christian religion. Einstein was never close to Christianity. He expressly renounced the Jewish belief of his ancestors.

So as Störig says it is no expression of "gläubig" in the classic (christian/jewish) religious way.

But

> In  seinem  Innern  war  Einstein  jedoch  ein  tief  religiöser  Mensch.
>
> Inside, however, Einstein was a deeply religious person.

Einstein's answer to the question: "Do you believe in God?" was

> "Ich  glaube an [Spinozas Gott](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spinozism), der sich in der gesetzlichen Harmonie des Seienden offenbart, nicht an einen Gott, der sich mit den Schicksalen und Handlungen der Menschen abgibt."
>
> "I do believe in Spinoza's God, who reveals himself in the legal harmony of beings, [but] not in a God who deals with the fates and actions of men".

Störig concludes

> Der Ausdruck „gläubige Physiker“ zielt offenbar nicht auf die Religion, sondern meint Menschen, die die Erkenntnisse der modernen Physik – zu denen Einstein das Kernstück beigesteuert hat – zur Grundlage ihres Weltbildes und ihrer Lebensanschauung gemacht haben.
>
> The expression "believing physicists" apparently does not refer to religion, but means people who have made the knowledge of modern physics - to which Einstein contributed the core - the basis of their worldview and their view of life.

Comment: Das *offenbar* empfinde ich als gemein. Es ist mir überhaupt nicht klar, wie das *gläubig* zu verstehen ist, und Störig liefert kein Argument wider die religiöse Deutung (das der Einschätzung vorangehende Zitat erfüllt diese Funktion für mich nicht).

Comment: May I - completely irrelevantly, of course - share the information that I used to know the amazing professor Störig and once had the extraordinary luck of drinking a bottle of wine with him? Thank you.

Comment: @DavidVogt: Ich verstehe deinen Einwand nicht so recht. Für mich klingt er so, als ginge es hier um das Wort "offensichtlich" (= "wie jeder ohne Weiteres erkennen kann", was aber oben nicht vorkommt). Was an "offenbar" (= "so, wie es scheint") auszusetzen wäre, wird mir nicht klar.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper Wieso ist *gläubig* in dem zitierten Satz *offenbar* (dem Anschein nach) nicht auf die Religion bezogen? Wodurch wird dieser Anschein erweckt?

Comment: @DavidVogt: "Offenbar" muss sich nicht auf Anhaltspunkte beziehen, die innerhalb des zitierten Satzes zu finden sind. Es drückt lediglich aus, dass der Autor *irgendwo* solche Anhaltspunkte zu erkennen glaubt, die ihn zu seiner Schlussfolgerung kommen lassen.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper Diese nicht zu nennen, empfinde ich als gemein. Das war der Ausgangskommentar.

Comment: @DavidVogt: Ahaaa - ich hatte vermutet, dass du "offenbar" als "offensichtlich" aufgefasst hattest und es nun gemein fandest, dass hier eine - deiner Meinung nach eben nicht offensichtliche -  Schlussfolgerung als nicht weiter erklärungsbedürftig (und der nicht verstehende Leser folglich als nicht beachtenswert) abgetan wird.